# How do I determine if a checkbox is checked to do something, then unchecked do something else?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, checkbox, checked

I have a PHP array that populates the IDs of checkboxes in a form, then used jQuery to capture those IDs.  Now I am having a hard time writing an If/Else statement to determine if the checkbox is checked, and if so do one thing, and if it's unchecked do something else.  This code works outside of the If statement, but as soon as I add any of the different methods to determine if it's checked or not, it stops working.

The different methods I have used are:  .click, .is(':checked'), .prop, and (this.checked) but nothing works.

This (and .change) works:

```
$('#' + product_array[i]).click(function(){

     alert(product_array[i]);

});
```

This (and all of the other methods mentioned above) does not:

```
$('#' + product_array[i]).click(function(){

    if(this.checked){
        alert('checked');
    }
    else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

Comment: `if(this.checked==true){}else{}`

Comment: I just tried that and that works, kinda, but backwards.  When I check the box, the "else" statement is triggered.  When I take away the else statement, it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked'))
    console.log("Checked");
   else
    console.log("UnCheck"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" />
```

**Solution 2**

You can use the class to listen to your checkbox `change` event like below.

```js
$(".myCheckBox").on("change", function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked'))
    console.log("Id: " + $(this).attr("id") + " Checked");
   else
    console.log("Id: " + $(this).attr("id") + " UnChecked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" id="1" />
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" id="2" />
<input class="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" id="3"/>
```

Comment: Since I am populating the IDs from a PHP array, how do I populate both the class and the id with a jquery array that I can use for this?

Comment: add your class in each `input` item.

Comment: On your first solution, it works, except how do I change: 
 $("input[type='checkbox'"].on('change', function.......

to being able to use:  $("#" + product_array)......  ?

When I tried it, only the "else" statement works and only "Uncheck" comes out.

Comment: Give me your HTML, **product_array** as well. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Checked attribute is a boolean attribute. So, `this.checked` will output either true or false. `true`-checked and `false`-unchecked.

```js
//$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
$("#one").click(function(){
   if(this.checked==true)
   {
    console.log("Checked");
    }
   else
   {
    console.log("UnCheck"); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="one" />
```

Comment: For some reason, this only says "unchecked" whether it's checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#checkb").change(function(){
$res=$(this).prop('checked')?'do something on check':'do on unchecked'
  console.log($res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check: <input type="checkbox" id='checkb' />
```